# Null pointer exception while inserting comma in Java

Tags: java

I have a character array. I have to insert ',' after 3rd character. I have written the following code.

```
    public class Comma {
    char [] str = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char [] buf = null;
    int size = str.length;
    int c=1;
    public void insert()
    {
      for(int i=0;i<size+10;i++)
      {
        c++;
        if(c==3)
        {
            buf[i]=',';
            i++;
            c=1;
        }
        buf[i]=str[i];
    }   
    for(int i=0;i<buf.length;i++)
    System.out.println("Final String is"+buf[i]);
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      Comma c = new Comma();
      c.insert();
   }
   }
```

When I run it, it is showing null pointer exception. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Which line throws the NPE? This information is always needed when debugging this type of problem.

Comment: Where did the NullPointerException occur?

Comment: @AnushaMallajosyula: you have your answer below, but understand that we don't know what "line 16 and 28" are. Next time you have a similar problem, **show us** *in your question* above which line via an obvious comment.

Comment: @AnushaMallajosyula, don't forget to mark the best answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char [] buf = null;` declared as `null` and you are accessing it    `buf[i]=',';`

try to declare like

```
char [] buf=new char[some range];
```

EXAMPLE:

```
 char [] buf=new char[8];
```

Comment: well d'oh!!! 1+ for finding this first.

Answer (score 2):

You used `buf.length`, but your buf is declared null.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized `char buf[]` and you are trying to assign value to it.You need to initialize it as below,

```
char [] buf=new char[10];
```

and then use it otherwise it will throw NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

In java you have to give the array size when you first create it, after that in can no changed.
So you will want to chance

`char [] buf = null;`

into

```
char [] buf = new char[10];
```

That way you will actually reserve space for the chars you want to place.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize  as follows

```
 char [] buf =new char[somevalue] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

buf is an array of size null. Hence the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here you declared `char [] buf = null;` as null and you are accessing it.

So buffer is null.So it is giving here NullPointerException.

Solution:

```
char [] buf = char[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize your array with some size

```
 char [] buf = char[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not initialize yr buf

use this

```
char [] buf = new char[str.length];
```